# Exchange 2010 SP3 Issues

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange, exchange-2010

I have just upgraded exchange 2010 SP1 to SP3, and had no issues during the installation. However, over the past few days users have had isues with creating mailboxes. "Load balancing failed to find a valid mailbox database."

On diagnosing this issue, I realised ther server has been using more RAM than usual after the upgrade. Now the RAM usage peaks at 97% on average. Restarting IIS was able to release some memory and the issue went away.

My question now is has anyone had such issues and also what could make store.exe use so much RAM.

Comment: Run `get-mailboxdatabase | ft name,isexcludedfromprovisioning` and let us know the output.

Comment: And are you on rollup 1 as well?

Comment: @TheCleaner I have done that and it is set for automatic provisioning. All set to "false". I am on Rollup 1 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exchange usually takes as much memory as there is available, then releases some of it when other processes require it but that of course creates various delays. We're running Exchange 2010 SP3 on a VM and haven't noticed any communication issues but it does eat up all available memory.

After a quick google found [this page](http://www.bursky.net/index.php/2012/05/limit-exchange-2010-memory-use/) which you can use to limit the memory usage by Exchange.